# Can we think of holonomic constraints as constraints which are state functions?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

While nonholonomic constraints are path functions. Because as holonomic constraints are those constraints which are the same for any system with all equivalent position coordinates, while nonholonomic constraints are different even for identical (position and time wise) configurations, and therefore depends on how that configuration was obtained, i.e. the path.